# Solution of ODE related to normal density

Tags: differential-equations, integration

This question below is from [mathse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886936/solution-of-differential-equation-related-to-normal-density). I reqeustioned here because very limited respond there.

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be the standard normal density, $$\phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Given $0<\sigma\le 1$. I wish to know whether there exists a "nice" solution $\alpha$ satisfying the differential equation 
$$\alpha''(u) [\phi(u) + \frac 1\sigma \phi(u/\sigma)] - \alpha'(u) [u\phi(u) + \frac 1{\sigma^3} u\phi(u/\sigma)] - \alpha(u)  [\phi(u) + \frac 1{\sigma^3} \phi(u/\sigma)] = \frac 1{\sigma^5} u\phi(u/\sigma).$$

For $\sigma=1$, I got that the explicit solution for the above differential equation is $\alpha(u)= -\frac 14 u + (a + b \Phi(u))/\phi(u)$ where $\Phi(u)=\int_{-\infty}^u\phi(x)dx.$ However, when $\sigma<1$ it really makes difficult in finding the solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you have $\frac1\sigma$ in the first coefficient and $\frac1{\sigma^3}$ in the next ones? It might be easier if they all had the same exponent.

Comment: Thanks @JoonasIlmavirta for your respond. Yes, the first coefficient is $\frac1\sigma$

Comment: Maple 18 finds no closed-form solution.  That doesn't necessarily mean there is none, but it is fairly strong evidence.  Do you have any reason to think there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: Thanks @Robert Israel for your respond. I don't any reason about the existence of the explicit solution bcause the question is a part of my research. I need the "nice" solution and not necessary explicit solution. For example when $\sigma=1$ then the solution could be expressed as normal density and cummulative function.

Comment: Maple does find the solution for $\sigma = 1$: the error function $\text{erf}$ is "closed form" as far as Maple is concerned.  More generally, Maple often finds solutions involving indefinite integrals and/or implicit functions if they exist.

Comment: A... OK @RobertIsrael. So, it means that the "closed-form" solution is nearly impossible, isn't it? Any suggestion then?

Comment: There are many possibilities, depending on what you want to do with the solutions.  For example, you might try expanding in a series in powers of $\sigma - 1$.

Comment: Would you mind telling me why it is worth to expand in a series in powers of $\sigma-1$?